# Merge changes in same file from two different revisions

Tags: svn, merge, revision

I had to do some signifanct mmanual erging work when I pulled the latest trunk into my branch. Now one of the files, I ran out of resources to do the merging on the spot and I "just" hit `tc` to accept their changes, losing my changes in the head revision.

Now, can I go back and merge my changes from the revision previous to the "merge commit@18178" to the current head and commit it back?

Essentially pulling out my old file and merging it to the latest revision (which sits @HEAD in my branch without my changes).

I've tried

```
$ svn merge src/rtos_core/jpax_sanity_check/@18177 src/rtos_core/jpax_sanity_check/@18178
```

but that gave me `Tree conflict` and didn't even display the original `merge conflicts`